# Проект под Android c внешней библиотекoй

Tags: android, java

Подключение внешней библиотеки к проекту под Anroid.

Я только начал изучение Android-a. Мне надо написать библиотеку для андроида. И для этого надо построить приложение, проверяющее библиотеку. Пока вроде всё нормально. Построил библиотеку, проверил её на Java на компе - всё ОК. Настроил простейшее приложение для андроида, запустил его - всё ещё всё ОК. Начал подключать библиотеку. Здесь пошли проблемы. Для начала сообщу, что работаю в Линуксе (может от этого все проблемы). Подключал библиотеку 3 способами.

1. Правый клик на проект->Properties->Android. Там, где написано Library, нажимаю Add  и выбираю проект с библиотекой (http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html).
2. В папку libs физически скопировал библиотеку(jar). F5-на обновление. Правый клик на файл библиотеки и выбираю Build Path->Add To Build Path (http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/library.php).
3. Правый клик на проект->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add External Jar. Дальше ОК, ОК, ОК... пока не закроется.

После всех 3 способов я получаю в LogCat такую хрень:

> Error - No such file or directory

Кто-то с таким сталкивался, кто-то знает, как проблему решить?

Comment: расскажи секрет, что там в твоей либе такого полезного?

Comment: Извините за оффтоп, но вот прям интересно, а какая операционка, вы считаете, работает лучше линухи?

Answer (score 1):

1. Создайте папку "libs" в корне проекта (если ее нет)
2. Скопируйте ваши jar фалы в неё
3. В Eclipse правый клик по jar файлу Build Path -> Add to Build Path, это должно создать папку "Referenced Library" в вашем проекте

Это удобно, если придется перемещать проект и(или) разработка ведется на разных компьютерах, ведь jar файл не потеряется.

Answer (score 0):

Положи свою либу в папку проекта libs (если нету такой - создай) и подключи 3м способом =)

Answer (score 0):

Создаете папку libs в корне проекта, кидаете туда свой JAR, обновляете проект(F5) и вуаля! Eclipse сам подхватывает jar-ы, лежащие в Libs.

Comment: Всем спасибо.Проблема решена.На самом деле проблема была во мне,т.е. в програме. Заметил поздно.